# Write azure function to convert pdf to image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, azure-functions

I am trying from the last two days to write the function on azure for converting PDF to image in JavaScript but not getting success.

I have tried to run the code on VSCode then I'm able to convert the pdf to image but when I write the same code on azure function I'm not getting success.

Various library I have used but still no success on azure function. like `pdf-poppler,pdf2img,pdf-image,pdf2pic` etc.

This code I have tried on VSCode:

```
const PDF2Pic = require("pdf2pic");

const pdf2pic = new PDF2Pic({
    quality: 1,
    density: 100,           // output pixels per inch
    savename: "untitled",   // output file name
    savedir: "hello",    // output file location
    format: "png",          // output file format
    size: "600x600"
});
console.log(pdf2pic);
pdf2pic.convert('response.pdf').then((resolve) => {
    console.log("image converter successfully!");

    return resolve;
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('error', err);
});
```

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Could you share the function code that you are trying? Also, do you get any error when trying to running it on Azure?

Comment: i have tried same function as above on Azure but it is not going inside the function .convert.then context.log('image converter successfully')

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get this to work. Your code had initially two problems that needed fixing:

1. Missing prerequisites
2. Incorrect file paths

Firstly, [pdf2pic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2pic) has prerequisites of:

- [GraphicsMagic](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm)
- [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download.html)

which I installed using brew:

```sh
brew install GraphicsMagic
brew install GhostScript
```

Secondly, the file paths need to be absolute with reference to the `savedir`, and input file to `pdf2pic.convert()`. The full Azure Function looks like this:

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

    const PDF2Pic = require("pdf2pic");

    const pdf2pic = new PDF2Pic({
        quality: 1,
        density: 100,           // output pixels per inch
        savename: "untitled",   // output file name
        savedir: "/path/to/savedir",    // output file location
        format: "png",          // output file formatt
        size: "600x600"
    });
    console.log(pdf2pic);
    pdf2pic.convert('/path/to/response.pdf').then((resolve) => {
        console.log("image converter successfully!");

        return resolve;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('error', err);
    });

    context.res = {
        status: 200
    }
};
```

See logs of successfully executing function:

```sh
[02/01/2020 02:37:11] Executing HTTP request: {
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   "requestId": "10fa33ea-5c2f-4384-8b50-3dac60cf38d6",
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   "method": "GET",
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   "uri": "/api/HttpTrigger"
[02/01/2020 02:37:11] }
[02/01/2020 02:37:11] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=d5373a17-cd80-4999-bf76-96c0c9635178)
[02/01/2020 02:37:11] t {
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   options: {
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]     quality: 1,
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]     format: 'png',
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]     size: '600x600',
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]     density: 100,
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]     savedir: '/path/to/savedir',
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]     savename: 'untitled',
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]     compression: 'jpeg'
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   }
[02/01/2020 02:37:11] }
[02/01/2020 02:37:11] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=d5373a17-cd80-4999-bf76-96c0c9635178)
[02/01/2020 02:37:11] Executed HTTP request: {
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   "requestId": "10fa33ea-5c2f-4384-8b50-3dac60cf38d6",
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   "method": "GET",
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   "uri": "/api/HttpTrigger",
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   "identities": [
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]     {
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]       "type": "WebJobsAuthLevel",
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]       "level": "Admin"
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]     }
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   ],
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   "status": 200,
[02/01/2020 02:37:11]   "duration": 559
[02/01/2020 02:37:11] }
[02/01/2020 02:37:12] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000003401D627'.
[02/01/2020 02:37:12] image converter successfully!
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you install the dependencies via the Azure Portal via command line? I.e. How did you get them on the server?

Comment: I did this locally via command line, haven't tried deploying to an actual function app. You *might* be able to install the dependencies with the `--additional-packages` option, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#project-file-deployment).